# Problem involving two Kronecker products related by an invertible matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, kronecker-product

I want to prove that if $A \otimes B = (C \otimes D)Z$ where $A,C \in M_m$ and $B, D \in M_n$ and $Z \in M_{m \times n}$ is invertible then there are invertible matrices $X$ and $Y$ such that $A = CX$ and $B = DY$.

I am stuck with trying to prove that $Z$ has to be equal to $X' \otimes Y'$ for some $X' \in M_m ,Y' \in M_n$ (I am pretty sure this is necessarily true). I have got as far as partitioning $Z$ into $m$ number of  $n \times n$ matrices $Y_{ij}$, and have shown (hopefully correctly) that all the $DY_{ij}$ are scalar multiples of one another, I want to show that the $Y_{ij}$'s are scalar multiples of one another.

Any hints would be much appreciated. Apart from showing that $Z$ has to be equal to $X' \otimes Y'$ for some $X',Y'$, I am okay with the rest of the problem.

Comment: I think it helps reframing the question as being about the images (= row spaces = ranges) of the matrices: You want to show that the images of $A$ and $C$ are equal (because that's equivalent to the existence of an invertible $X$ with $A = CX$), and likewise for $B$ and $D$. So you want to reconstruct the images of $A$ and $B$ from the image of $A \otimes B$. This sounds like it could be done **under the assumption that $A$ and $B$ are nonzero**. If $A$ or $B$ is zero, then your claim is wrong.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I find your hint very interesting and will have a think about it, thank you

Comment: @darijgrinberg I can reconstruct the image of $B$ from $A \otimes B$ but don't know how to reconstruct the image of $A$ from $A \otimes B$, could you please give me a hint?

Comment: Very nice. Now, there is a symmetry between $A$ and $B$ that you might not be seeing if you define Kronecker products in the matrix way. Even so, it is easy to use: There is an explicit permutation matrix $T$ such that $B \otimes A = T \left(A \otimes B\right) T^{-1}$ and $D \otimes C = T \left(C \otimes D\right) T^{-1}$. Thus, if you can reconstruct $A$ from $A \otimes B$, then you can also reconstruct $B$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg Thank you so much. My textbook doesn't have this theorem.

Comment: This theorem becomes obvious once you learn that the Kronecker product of two matrices is just a special indexing of the tensor product of two linear maps (and tensor products are symmetric).